# How to change the .Net assembly lookup order

Tags: c#, .net, dll

We are working on Host-Plugin model based application, where the host exe (long running) loads the plugin dll using reflection based on the request, performs some operation (over standard plugin interface) and returns the result. Contents of the plugin folder are not in our control.

The folder structure looks like this -

```
\
+--Host.exe
+--C.dll
+--Z.dll
+--PluginA
|  +--PluginA.dll
|  +--C.dll
|  +--D.dll
```

At run time `\Host.exe` loads `\PluginA\PluginA.dll` using reflection, and the `\PluginA\PluginA.dll` references `C.dll`. .NET looks for `C.dll` first in `\` and finds and loads `\C.dll`, instead of `\PluginA\C.dll`. Now `C.dll` references `D.dll`, but since `D.dll` is not present in root `\`, the lookup fails.

Is there a way I can modify the look-up order of dlls in .NET, such that **it first looks in the folder of calling assembly (dll) and then in the folder of the calling exe?**
In this case (lookup of `C.dll`, where the calling assembly was `\PluginA\PluginA.dll`) the order should be -

```
/PluginA
/
```

**If this is not possible, what is the recommended solution/approach for this scenario?**

Comment: Preload assemblies yourself or use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks a lot for you response. I checked `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` and it fires when the assembly load has failed, so it will help `\C.dll` load `\PluginA\D.dll`. But it will not help `\PluginA\PluginA.dll` load `\PluginA\C.dll`. How can I do that? Is there any pre-load event for assembly?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the difference. To my knowledge AssemblyResolve will always fire when assembly is not found... If you saying that *you* don't know where to load assembly from too in that case than it is not really problem with that event...If you afraid it will load the wrong one - preload is more or less the only option, but having conflicting non-strongly named assemblies is recipe for disaster and you should then rethink your approach.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I'll try and explain again, when `\PluginA\PluginA.dll` tries to load `C.dll`, it expects to load `\PluginA\C.dll` but due to the search order of .Net it ends up loading `\C.dll`. So, technically there is no assembly load failure, it just loads the wrong assembly. So. `AssemblyResolve` will not help with this, right? What I want is that .Net should look for the assembly first in the folder of the calling assembly, or if there is assembly pre-load event then based on the calling assembly I can load from the right folder.

Comment: Hope this makes it clear, I'll request to read the question again to get an idea of the folder structure. Thanks a lot for your help so far, really appreciate it.

Comment: As I said you have to pre-load all assemblies from the folder in that case... Also I strongly recommend rethinking what you are trying to avoid - two plugins using different versions of the same non-strongly-named assembly will bring you real chaos... Not much you can do short of creating separate appdomains (which will also let you specify load path).

Comment: Note that you can not avoid using *already loaded* assembly (which is the reason for my warning in previous comment)